# Using OOXML For a paragraph I want to set Line spacing value to single

Tags: c#, openxml

Using OOXML for a paragraph I am able to set the spacing after and Before value 

Following is the code

```
paragraphProperties1.SpacingBetweenLines = new SpacingBetweenLines() { After = "0", Before = "0" };
```

I want to set the Line spacing to a single value.
[Please check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpkZY.jpg)

Comment: C# is the language

Comment: Please edit your question and add C# to the list of tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I open a fresh Word doc, type in some text, set the paragraph settings to 0 points before, 0 points after and "Single" and then save the document, I see this in the Open Xml Productivity tool (a tool you should be using):

```
Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph(){ RsidParagraphAddition = "00977688", RsidParagraphProperties = "00ED3794", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00ED3794" };

ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
SpacingBetweenLines spacingBetweenLines1 = new SpacingBetweenLines(){ After = "0", Line = "240", LineRule = LineSpacingRuleValues.Auto };

paragraphProperties1.Append(spacingBetweenLines1);
```

At first glance, the difference seems to be the `LineRule = LineSpacingRuleValues.Auto`.  That tool (downloadable from the Microsoft site) is invaluable when using Open XML.  You can use it to see the code that represents a document (the "Reflect Code" button), or to see the differences between two documents (the "Compare Files" button).

The Compare operation is particularly useful.  For example, if I took my test Word document and saved it before setting the paragraph setting to "Single", and then set the setting to "Single" and saved another copy, then I could compare the two documents and that one change would be highlighted.

When I do that, I can see that the difference I can see that the difference is the `Line = "240"` part.  I get the `LineRule = LineSpacingRuleValues.Auto` on both versions.

By the way, you should be able to ignore the *RsidXxxx* constants - if I remember correctly, those are for versioning things.

Comment: That tool (the OpenXML Productivity Tool) is your friend - if you are doing _anything_ with Open XML